# 15.10 - Cannot connect to wireless networks at home, but can at remote locations?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet, intel-wireless

Ever since I plugged in an ethernet cable into my laptop at home I cannot connect to the wireless network anymore. It doesn't list any of them.
Before it was working fine.

The weird part is, whenever I am at a different location, I can connect to and find any wireless network.

I am not too familiar with unix but I ran `rfkill list all` and nothing is soft or hard blocked and it does list Wifi:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also `sudo lshw -C network` shows nothing out of the ordinary. (Note I ran these command with the ethernet cable plugged in).

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 3c:d9:2b:25:53:5b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.5-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.2.33 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:38 memory:d1500000-d151ffff memory:d152a000-d152afff ioport:5020(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 34
       serial: a0:88:b4:86:0a:1d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.2.0-36-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:41 memory:d1200000-d1201fff
```

So what can be the cause of this weird issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script while you  are at home (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it

Answer (score 0):

Windows offers automatic switching between Access Points and channels to find the best connection. Ubuntu comes with GNOME Network Manager that does not offer this fuctionality.

This will cause problems if you use your laptop in a congested enviroment with many access points and many channels. Look at this section of the results of your WiFi script.

```
Channel occupancy:

      4   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      5   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
      7   APs on   Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
      6   APs on   Frequency:5.745 GHz (Channel 149)
```

You are using channel 1. Lets look at that in more detail, again from the results of your wireless script. The 4 access points are

```
UCSD-PROTECTED
eduroam
UCSD-GUEST
UCSD-DEVICE
```

and you are connected to the first of these. This is probably the access point and channel the majority of non-Windows users are connected to so it is massively overloaded.

The next Channel that has access points is channel 6. The access points are

```
UCSD-PROTECTED
eduroam
UCSD-GUEST
UCSD-GUEST
UCSD-DEVICE
```

and so on ad nauseum. All of these access points are contending with each other and since the network administrator who created this chaos did not include the channel number in the channel name there is no easy way to manually ensure you connect to the best access point and channel.

To solve this you need to get your computer to do the hard work through a script such as [getwifi](http://getwifi.sourceforge.net/) .